# AS3 Frame script executing immediately rather than when specified

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

I have the following code which should add a `MovieClip` and add a frame script to the `MovieClip` to be executed once the clip has finished playing.  The code shown below however triggers the frame script as soon as the `MovieClip` is added and I can't figure out why.

```
function debugClick(e:MouseEvent) : void
{    
  nextLevAnim = new NextLevelAnim();
  gfx.addChild(nextLevAnim);
  nextLevAnim.addFrameScript(nextLevAnim.totalFrames, NextLevel);
}

function NextLevel() : void
{
  nextLevAnim.addFrameScript(nextLevAnim.totalFrames, null);

  // Actions....
}
```

I've tried with simpler examples and it works fine, the `MovieClip` is 21 frames long and I've tried triggering the frame script by `totalFrames` and `totalFrames - 1`, running out of ideas!

Comment: Meaning what exactly? I tried `totalFrames - 1` and got the same result.

Comment: Meaning it's nextLevAnim.totalFrames - 1. Did you include stop() on the NextLevelAnim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, I haven't worked with `addFrameScript` much so I can't tell what is causing the problems, but you could try using a hack.

use an onEnterFrame listener and check if the current frame equals the number of frames (-1).
it's not ideal, but if you're stuck on this it might just do.

as far as `addFrameScript` goes, my guess is that it's not working because addMovieClip doesn't take effect until the render part of cycle, so the totalframes are still 0 for the child added. You can add a listener for `onAddedToStage` or `onAdded` and add the addFrameScript event handler after the `MovieClip` gets initialized

Comment: This is what I ended up doing for now, not ideal but hey if it works, it works!

Answer (score 0):

What is `totalFrames` variable in this case? Have you tried to `trace()` it? I'm pretty sure it does not contain the proper value of the total number of frames in `nextLevAnim` and you should probably use `nextLevAnim.totalFrames` instead.

Comment: Sorry that's a typo, should have been `nextLevAnim.totalFrames`. I've used trace to determine the function `NextLevel()` is being called as soon as the frame script is declared rather than when nextLevAnim finished playing.